# ROS 2 Humble Building From source issues on BeagleBone Black, Ubuntu 22.04.3

Tags: ros-humble, build-from-source

I need to build ROS 2 Humble from source on a Beaglebone Black. When I do so, I get build errors. I followed the instructions on the ROS website.

As shown in the screenshot below, warning occur indicating some C++ expressions changed with gcc 7.1. Is there a specific compiler version required to build ROS 2 from source?

I also tried building with 'colcon build --symlink-intall --continue-on-error' and the build stops after 6 failures and 130 successful package builds. The output of this can also be found as the second screenshot provided.

If anyone has experience building ROS 2 Humble from source on armhf architecture or is aware of what is causing this issue, please let me know. If more information is required, please let me know as I am new to Linux and ROS.

Thank you
[image: Build output without continue on error]

[image: Build with continue on error]

Answer (score 0):

First: don't post text output as screenshots. Instead: copy-paste it in a code block, between ``` delimiters, e.g.:

> ```
>
> [copy - paste]
>
> ```

Now, wrt the error: it is about RViz (`rviz_ogre_vendor`). I assume you don't need to run RViz on the Beaglebone. So I suggest to use `colcon graph` to check the dependencies of `rviz_ogre_vendor`, and just remove that package and all its dependencies from your source tree.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I will ensure the terminal output is added as text moving forward. As for removing packages from the build process, Ideally I would build the core packages and only build additional packages as required. Is there a way with colcon to build only the core packages? Or would I have to find the name of each core package and omit all others?

Comment: I don't know unfortunately.. I found [this thread](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/870) in which [the part on `rosinstall_generator`](https://github.com/ros2/ros2_documentation/issues/870#issuecomment-683938376) seems th most promising, but I have no experience with that.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your help.